# How to find the shortest distance/ travel time between two airports?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem was created by me, discussed with my co-workers and no one seem to have an idea. Thus, thought, I can ask the experts here.

I've the following table
  FlightInfo and the fields are

```
 Start
 Destination
 Flight_Duration
```

The goal is to find out, the shortest flight between two cities. The challenge is not all cities have direct flights. (Example: PHL to PVA ->Philadelphia to Shangai). You have to connect in Detroit (DTW) or Chicago (ORD)

How will you go about writing an SQL statement?

Example table contents

PHL   DTW   2.25

DTW   PVG  15.15

PHL   ORD   3.15

ORD   PVG   16.20

Comment: Question lacks pertinent details - tables, data, expected output.  You expect us to hack into SABRE for you, or something?

Comment: There are existing implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm in various SQL variants.

Comment: Shortest path problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: @OMG -> This is purely to keep the knowledge cells alive. No hacking to SABRE etc., As I had written, I've a table with just 3 fields with my own data.

Comment: @relet ->I'm wondering, if it is possible to write an SQL statement for the same.

Comment: Wait... those times are flight durations? You rather need a schedule if you want to find a quickest way from A to B. I mean, take off date/time - landing date/time.

Comment: @skallee -> You are correct. I'm just trying to find out how you achieve this in SQL. This is purely for experimental purposes only and not for real world applications.

Comment: There may be some insight over in the GIS StackExchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/ though the details may be more than you're looking for: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-do-i-find-the-distance-between-two-coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force:

```
declare @t table (
 [from] char(3), 
 [to] char(3),
 [time] float);

 insert into @t 
    ([from], [to], [time])
values  
 ('PHL', 'DTW', 2.25),
 ('DTW', 'PVG', 15.15),
 ('PHL', 'ORD', 3.15),
 ('ORD', 'PVG', 16.20);

 declare @src char(3) = 'PHL',
   @dst char(3) = 'PVG';

with cteAnchor as (
select case @src 
    when [from] then [to] 
    when [to] then [from]
    end as [layover], [time]
    , [time] as [total]
    , cast([from]+'-'+[to] as varchar(max)) as [path]
    , 1 as [flights]
from @t
where @src in ([from], [to]))
, cteRecursive as (
select [layover], [time], [total], [path], [flights]
from cteAnchor
union all
select case r.layover
    when [from] then [to]
    when [to] then [from] 
    end as [layover]
    , t.[time]
    , t.[time] + r.[total] as [total]
    , r.[path] + ' ' +t.[from]+'-'+t.[to] as [path]
    , r.[flights] + 1
from @t t
join cteRecursive r
    on  (t.[from] = r.[layover] and 0 = charindex(t.[to], r.[path]))
        or 
        (t.[to] = r.[layover] and 0 = charindex(t.[from], r.[path]))
)
select top(1) [flights], [total], [path] from cteRecursive  
where @dst = [layover]
order by [total] asc;
```

Answer:

```
total   path
17.4    PHL-DTW DTW-PVG
```

Edit note: I have modified the implementation of the CTE with one which is resilient to cycles and is also actually correct.

Comment: Your performance mileage may vary (as in 'don't do this in a real case'). This is more of an academic exercise, much like the question.

Comment: Thanks Remus Rusanu. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an assumption that you may get from any single airport to any another one in at most three flights. It is possible that it won't be true in few very exceptional cases, but is this really a problem? I don't think so, however you may consider adding another join if you feel you need it.

```
Table flights:
origin      VARCHAR
destination VARCHAR
start       DATETIME
end         DATETIME
```

And query:

```
SELECT *, f3.end - f1.end AS duration
FROM flights AS f1
INNER JOIN flights AS f2
ON f1.destination = f2.origin AND f1.end < f2.start
INNER JOIN flights AS f3
ON f2.destination = f3.origin AND f2.end < f3.start
WHERE f1.start BETWEEN some_reasonable_values_not_to_have_too_many_rows_in_join
  AND f2.start BETWEEN some_reasonable_values_not_to_have_too_many_rows_in_join
  AND f3.start BETWEEN some_reasonable_values_not_to_have_too_many_rows_in_join
  AND f1.origin = your_desired_origin
  AND f3.destination = your_desired_destination
ORDER BY duration ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This is for combination of three flights. Similar SQL for two flights and one flight (less joins). Then, union those three queries and take the best result.

You may want to add some minimal delay between flights. `Some_reasonable_values_not_to_have_too_many_rows_in_join` - does it make sense to search flight combinations that take longer than e.g. three days?